# Handling Waitfor Popup & select window using Ruby Webdriver

Tags: ruby, rubygems, selenium-webdriver

When I tried exporting Selenium IDE capture into Ruby - webdriver, I get the following for waitforpopup and select window scenarios.

```
ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [waitForPopUp |  | 30000]]
# ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [selectWindow | title=TestQA - Des2013 | ]]
```

How do I handle similar situation using ruby webdriver, as we used to do in selenium RC.

selenium.waitforpopup(windowname, 3000)

selenium.selectWindow(windowname)

Answer (score 0):

Some commands cannot be exported to ruby/rspec scripts.

Is that an overlay? If yes, you can just interact with it with no problem.

Is that another frame? you can use the code below

`driver.switch_to.frame "some-frame" # name or id
driver.switch_to.frame driver.find_element(:id, 'some-frame') # frame element`

Is that another tab/window? you can use the code below

`driver.switch_to.window("<window_handle>")`